# How can I optimize response time in this python code? (django)

Tags: python, django, algorithm, optimization, response

The **get_assets** method obtains a list of assets from the database and for each item in the list calls the **__build_asset_response** method to build a response in dictionary format. However, when there are many assets, the time to do the build_asset_response is very high. Does anyone know a method to optimize the time?

```
def get_assets(user, data):
    if data.get('asset_id'):
        assets = Asset.objects.filter(pk__in=data['asset_id'])
        return [__build_asset_response(asset) for asset in assets]
    assets = Asset.objects.filter(QueryHelper.filter_by_rol(user))
  
    return [__build_asset_response(asset) for asset in assets]
```

This is the buil_asset_response private method:

```
def __build_asset_response(asset):

    asset_dict = {
        'id': asset.pk,
        'name': asset.name,
        'accessibility': manage_accessibility.build_accessibility_type_response(asset.accessibility),
        'folder': "",
        'user_id': {
            'id': asset.user.id,
            'name': str(asset.user)
        },
        'organization': {
            'id': asset.idOrganization.id,
            'name': str(asset.idOrganization),
        },
        'asset_type_id': asset.idAssetType and __build_asset_type_response(asset.idAssetType) or {},
        'file': settings.MEDIA_URL + asset.archivo.name,
        'tag_ids': [tag.name for tag in asset.tag_ids.all()],
        'lastModified': timezone.localtime(asset.last_modified_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        'used_in_publication': asset.used_in_publication
    }
    if asset.idFolder:
        folder = manage_folder.build_folder_response(asset.idFolder)
    else:
        folder = ''
    asset_dict.update({
        'folder': folder,
    })

    return asset_dict
```

Comment: To optimize, you must first figure out where the time is going. That said, https://betterprogramming.pub/django-select-related-and-prefetch-related-f23043fd635d may help you with an obvious problem. Also be sure you have appropriate database indexes.

Comment: Hi. __build_asset_response(asset) for asset in assets this is the code line wich is taking a lot of time.  Is the iteration in order to build the response.

Comment: @Aymanete Have you looked at the link he sent? What he's getting at is; you're doing a lot of extra queries for every asset.

Comment: can you provide definition for build_folder_response() method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @So what can I do to in order to not make that large amount of extra querys?

Comment: @AmitaPatil. All thjose methos are simple dictionary builders. They not access to DB.